# Preserve theme style of control while modifying the control template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, mvvm

I'm trying to add bind some commands to `Slider.Thumb` and this is how I currently do it:

```
<Style x:Key="BasicSliderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type customControls:ThumbDragSlider}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Slider}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
                <Grid>
                    <Track x:Name="PART_Track">
                        <Track.Thumb>
                            <Thumb x:Name="Thumb">
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                                        <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding PositionSliderThumbMouseEnterCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="DragDelta">
                                        <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding PositionThumbDragDeltaCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=sMovieSkipSlider}"/>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            </Thumb>
                        </Track.Thumb>
                    </Track>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The problem is that I also have a theme applied to my controls and if I use this style the style and effects from it are removed as well, is there a way to keep the current application theme style on a control while also being able to add event triggers and attach commands as show above?

P.S - Since this is a custom control that derives from `Slider`, this is how I set the default theme style for the slider to it

```
Style="{StaticResource {x:Type Slider}}"
```

Comment: Can you provide the xaml for the theme applied to the slide on which the BasicSliderStyle is based ?

Comment: I can but it's very long and themes are changeable at runtime

Comment: If i am getting you right, both styles set the Template, and you are looking for a way to combine them both in you slider?

Comment: The theme style only changes the look of the control and the one in the question allows some commands to be attached, I want the slider to keep the theme look and also have the thumb events binder.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use Triggers in the Style and not in the Template, if you want to keep the same theme for that control. 
That means that it is not possible in your case. What you can do is copy the entire Style of your theme and specify the trigger there.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend your custom style. Instead of:

```
BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Slider}}"
```

do:

```
BasedOn="{StaticResource MyCustomSlider}"
```